# How to rename the exisitng cell names based on number of their occurnaces in a particular column?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, csv, xls

I have a column in my excel as below:

```
REF
---------
BV1013_1
BV1013_1
BV1013_2
BV1013_2
BV1026
BV1040
BV1040
BV1041
BV1041
BV1042
BV1042
```

**Desired OUTPUT:** Some of the cell values/names are same at several places. I would like to rename my cell names as below based on their number of occurrences.

```
REF             Desire
-----------------------
BV1013_1    BV1013_1_1  
BV1013_1    BV1013_1_2
BV1013_2    BV1013_2_1  
BV1013_2    BV1013_2_2
BV1026      BV1026_1
BV1040      BV1040_1
BV1040      BV1040_2
BV1041      BV1041_1
BV1041      BV1041_2
BV1042      BV1042_1
BV1042      BV1042_2
```

I would like to solve this in excel or using bash scripting. Any help is very valuable for me.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Excel spreadsheets aren't easily manipulated via bash scripts - if you convert your data to text or CSV then you could easily use something like `awk` though e.g. `awk -F, '{$1 = sprintf("%s_%d",$1,++seen[$1])} 1' ref.csv`

Comment: Hi steeldriver, I have changed the format to .csv. Can you please explain how does it work exactly (awk -F, '{$1 = sprintf("%s_%d",$1,++seen[$1])} 1' ref.csv), i have tried this not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) starting from

```
REF
BV1013_1
BV1013_1
BV1013_2
BV1013_2
BV1026
BV1040
BV1040
BV1041
BV1041
BV1042
BV1042
```

and running

```
mlr --csv step -a counter -f REF -g REF then put '$Desire=$REF."_".$REF_counter' then cut -x -f REF_counter input.csv
```

you will have

```
REF,Desire
BV1013_1,BV1013_1_1
BV1013_1,BV1013_1_2
BV1013_2,BV1013_2_1
BV1013_2,BV1013_2_2
BV1026,BV1026_1
BV1040,BV1040_1
BV1040,BV1040_2
BV1041,BV1041_1
BV1041,BV1041_2
BV1042,BV1042_1
BV1042,BV1042_2
```